# Grothendieck group of complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are given a complete intersection $X$ in some $\mathbb{P}^n$. What is the Grothendieck group $K_0(X)$ ? What assumption do we have to make if we want $K_0(X)$ to be free?

Comment: This is a completely inaccessible problem. If you know anything about GRR and it giving you an isomorphism of $K_0(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ with the rational chow ring, then you should know that this is an extremely difficult problem. Even computing the chow ring of a curve is a difficult problem which requires an enormous amount of machinery.